# Calculate rolling past 3 months average sales and it should filter with year month filter

Tags: powerbi

[image]

Task to Perform: Calculate rolling past 3 months average sales and it should filter with year month filter. (eg if April 2020 is selected it should show sales for (Jan+Feb+March)/3)

I have two tables 1. d - Calendar Table (Date, MonthName, Year as my columns) & 2. F-Sales Table (Date, Sales). I have created a relationship between the two tables. Can anyone please tell me how to get the above requirement using DAX Measure from Scratch!! / DAX Measure code for reference
[image]

The Result I need and output should look like the below image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0QyW.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**
Hi you can use inbuild rolling average measure in PBI. in order to access the click on the dropdown in the calendar field in the chart or graph and click on quick measures.

[image]

after the select rolling average from the menu as below.

[image]

configure your measure according to requirement.

[image]

If you need rolling average from scratch please let me know. this is how pbi has implemented, it but we can use DAX to create custom functions too

**Method 2**
Implement this by using measures. First create sum of sales by using below formula (please implement your columns in the formula)

```
VAR sum_sales = CALCULATE(SUM(Sales), DATESINPERIOD(DATE,LastDate(date),3, Month)

VAR days_in_period = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Date), DATESINPERIOD(Date,Lastdate(date), 3, Month)

return DIVIDE(sum_sales, days_in_period)
```

Comment: Hi Sir, thank you for the response I have done this using measure, but the result I need is different from the output it is throwing the above method

Comment: I have added the method 2 please have a look!!!